# Pytorch CNN error: Expected input batch_size (4) to match target batch_size (64)

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I've been teaching myself this since November and any help on this would be really appreciated, thank you for looking, as I seem to be going round in circles. I am trying to use a Pytorch CNN example that was used with the Mnist dataset. Now I am trying to modify the CNN for facial key point recognition.  I am using the Kaggle dataset (CSV) of 7048 training images and key points (15 key points per face) and 1783 test images.  I split training dataset and converted the images to jpeg, made separate file for the key points (shape 15, 2). I have made dataset and data loader and can iterate through and display images and plot key points. When I run the CNN I am getting this error.

```
> Net(
  (conv1): Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2))
  (conv2): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2))
  (conv2_drop): Dropout2d(p=0.5)
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=589824, out_features=100, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=30, bias=True)
)
Data and target shape:  torch.Size([64, 96, 96])   torch.Size([64, 15, 2])
Data and target shape:  torch.Size([64, 1, 96, 96])   torch.Size([64, 15, 2])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keith/PycharmProjects/FacialLandMarks/WorkOut.py", line 416, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/keith/PycharmProjects/FacialLandMarks/WorkOut.py", line 412, in main
    train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
  File "/home/keith/PycharmProjects/FacialLandMarks/WorkOut.py", line 324, in train
    loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
  File "/home/keith/Desktop/PycharmProjects/fkp/FacialLandMarks/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1788, in nll_loss
    .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (4) to match target batch_size (64).

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here are some links I have read, I could not figure out the problem
but may help some one else.

> > https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/11762
> >         [How do I modify this PyTorch convolutional neural network to accept a 64 x 64 image and properly output predictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53875372/how-do-i-modify-this-) 
> >             pytorch-convolutional-neural-network-to-accept-a-64-x-64-im
> >         [Pytorch Validating Model Error: Expected input batch_size (3) to match target batch_size (4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178922/pytorch-validating-) 
> >             model-error-expected-input-batch-size-3-to-match-target-ba

Here is my code:

```
    class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=(2, 2))
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=(2, 2))
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 96 * 96, 100)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 30)  # 30 is x and y key points

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 96 * 96)
        # x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        # x = x.view(x.size()[0], 30, -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)


def train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        data = batch['image']
        target = batch['key_points']
        print('Data and target shape: ', data.shape, ' ', target.shape)
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        data = data.unsqueeze(1).float()

        print('Data and target shape: ', data.shape, ' ', target.shape)

        output = model(data)
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % args.log_interval == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))


# def test(args, model, device, test_loader):
#     model.eval()
#     test_loss = 0
#     correct = 0
#     with torch.no_grad():
#         for data, target in test_loader:
#             data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
#             output = model(data)
#             test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, reduction='sum').item() # sum up batch loss
#             pred = output.max(1, keepdim=True)[1] # get the index of the max log-probability
#             correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()
#
#     test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
#     print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
#         test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
#         100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))



def main():
    # Training settings
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Project')
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=64, metavar='N',
                        help='input batch size for training (default: 64)')
    parser.add_argument('--test-batch-size', type=int, default=1000, metavar='N',
                        help='input batch size for testing (default: 1000)')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=10, metavar='N',   # ========  epoch
                        help='number of epochs to train (default: 10)')
    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=0.01, metavar='LR',
                        help='learning rate (default: 0.01)')
    parser.add_argument('--momentum', type=float, default=0.5, metavar='M',
                        help='SGD momentum (default: 0.5)')
    parser.add_argument('--no-cuda', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='disables CUDA training')
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=1, metavar='S',
                        help='random seed (default: 1)')
    parser.add_argument('--log-interval', type=int, default=10, metavar='N',
                        help='how many batches to wait before logging training status')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    use_cuda = not args.no_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available()

    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)

    device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")

    kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': True} if use_cuda else {}
    train_data_set = FaceKeyPointDataSet(csv_file='faces/Kep_points_and_id.csv',
                                         root_dir='faces/',
                                         transform=transforms.Compose([
                                             # Rescale(96),
                                             ToTensor()
                                         ]))

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_data_set, batch_size=args.batch_size,
                              shuffle=True)

    print('Number of samples: ', len(train_data_set))
    print('Number of train_loader: ', len(train_loader))

    model = Net().to(device)
    print(model)
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr, momentum=args.momentum)

    for epoch in range(1, args.epochs + 1):
        train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
        # test(args, model, device, test_loader)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: can you print the shape of `output`? I think you somehow manage to return output with batch size 4 instead of 64

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking, no I cant, trying to now.

Comment: Yes, made a few changes and got this: Output shape:  torch.Size([4, 30]).

Comment: I suspect the view(-1,...) in your code. check the dimension

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean.  I've played about with these values and still not running. I thought the -1 would be OK because its if your unsure of the number of rows, however the length of the columns are not all the same, could this be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to understand what went wrong you can print shape after every step in forward :

```
# Input data
torch.Size([64, 1, 96, 96])
x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
torch.Size([64, 32, 48, 48])
x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
torch.Size([64, 64, 24, 24])
x = x.view(-1, 64 * 96 * 96)
torch.Size([4, 589824])
x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
torch.Size([4, 100])
x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
torch.Size([4, 100])
x = self.fc2(x)
torch.Size([4, 30])
return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)    
torch.Size([4, 30])
```

- Your `maxpool2d` layers reduce the height and width of your feature maps.
- The 'view' should be `x = x.view(-1, 64 * 24 * 24)`
- the first linear layer of size : `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 24 * 24, 100)`

this will give your `output = model(data)` final shape of `torch.Size([64, 30])`

But this code will still face a problem in calculating the Negative Log Likelihood Loss :

> The input is expected to contain scores for each class. input has to
>   be a 2D Tensor of size (minibatch, C). This criterion expects a class
>   index (0 to C-1) as the target for each value of a 1D tensor of size
>   minibatch

where class indices are just labels :

> values representing a class. For example:
>
> 0 - class0,  1 - class1,

Since your last nn layer outputs a softmax over 30 classes, i'm assuming that is the output classes you want to classify into, 
so transformation for target :

```
target = target.view(64, -1) # gives 64X30 ie, 30 values per channel
loss = F.nll_loss(x, torch.max(t, 1)[1]) # takes max amongst the 30 values as class label
```

This is when the target is a probability distribution over 30 classes, if not can do a soft-max before that. Thus the maximum value in the 30 values will represent the highest probability - thus that class which is exactly what your output represents and thus you calculate a nll between the two values. .

Comment: Thank so much  Saleem cant wait to get back home to try it, il post in about 12 hours

Comment: I made changes but getting this this now: RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Double for argument #2 'target' . I should have said I'm new to python too

Comment: Hi this is still not working I now get this error: RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.LongTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same
When I change input to float I then get this error:  RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'target Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: can you update question with current implementation of target transform ? input data to module layers should be float. target for nll loss should be long generally speaking

Comment: Hello, I have it working now but only for one epoch and then I get the following error::  
    main()
  File "/home/keith/PycharmProjects/FacialLandMarks/WorkOut.py", line 446, in main
    train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
  File "/home/keith/PycharmProjects/FacialLandMarks/WorkOut.py", line 348, in train
    target = target.view(64, -1)  # gives 64X30 ie, 30 values per channel
RuntimeError: shape '[64, -1]' is invalid for input of size 270

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: please  ensure shape of 'target' before that view statement is torch.Size([64, 15, 2]) as you stated originally. for ease, instead of hardcode 64 do : `  target = target.view(target.shape[0], -1) `

Comment: Hello.I printed out target.size  when I change the code to [0, -1] the very last target size changes from torch.Size([64, 15, 2]) to torch.Size([9, 15, 2]) in between the two torch sizes i get this error now:  raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError thank you for looking.

Comment: If I leave code as was how does the batch size change to 9?

Comment: Saleem figured out last issue. I hadnt commented out my test method as i need to rewrite for loop. Silly mistake. Thank you for all your help. Really appreciated it