# Batch size keeps on changin, throwing `Pytorch Value Error Expected: input batch size does not match target batch size`

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am working on a multilabel text classification task with Bert.

The following is the code for generating an iterable Dataset.

```
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler

train_set = TensorDataset(X_train_id,X_train_attention, y_train)
test_set = TensorDataset(X_test_id,X_test_attention,y_test)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(
    train_set,
    sampler = RandomSampler(train_set),
    drop_last=True,
    batch_size=13
)

test_dataloader = DataLoader(
    test_set,
    sampler = SequentialSampler(test_set),
    drop_last=True,
    batch_size=13
)
```

The following are the the dimensions of the training set:

In[]

```
print(X_train_id.shape)
print(X_train_attention.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

Out[]

```
torch.Size([262754, 512])
torch.Size([262754, 512])
torch.Size([262754, 34])
```

There should be 262754 rows each with 512 columns. The output should predict the values from 34 possible labels. I am breaking them down into batches of 13.

Training code

```
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5)
# Training
def train(model):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
        b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
        b_labels = batch[2].to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss, logits = model(b_input_ids, 
                             token_type_ids=None, 
                             attention_mask=b_input_mask, 
                             labels=b_labels)
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item()
    return train_loss


# Testing
def test(model):
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in test_dataloader:
            b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
            b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
            b_labels = batch[2].to(device)
            with torch.no_grad():        
                (loss, logits) = model(b_input_ids, 
                                    token_type_ids=None, 
                                    attention_mask=b_input_mask,
                                    labels=b_labels)
            val_loss += loss.item()
    return val_loss

# Train task
max_epoch = 1
train_loss_ = []
test_loss_ = []

for epoch in range(max_epoch):
    train_ = train(model)
    test_ = test(model)
    train_loss_.append(train_)
    test_loss_.append(test_)
```

Out[]

```
Expected input batch_size (13) to match target batch_size (442).
```

This is the description of my model:

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification, AdamW, BertConfig

model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking", # 日本語Pre trainedモデル
    num_labels = 34, 
    output_attentions = False,
    output_hidden_states = False,
)
```

I have clearly stated that I want the batch size to be 13. However, during the training process pytorch is throwing a Runtime Error

Where is the number 442 even coming from? I have clearly stated that I want each batch to have a size of 13 rows.

I have already confirmed that each batch has input_id with dimensions [13,512], attention tensor with dimensions [13,512], and labels with dimensions [13,34].

I have tried caving in and using a batch size of 442 when initializing the DataLoader, but after a single batch iteration, it throws another `Pytorch Value Error Expected:  input batch size does not match target batch size`, this time showing:

```
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (442) to match target batch_size (15028).
```

Why does the batch size keep on changing? Where is the number 15028 even coming from?

The following are some of the answers I have looked through, but had no luck on applying to my source code:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/valueerror-expected-input-batch-size-324-to-match-target-batch-size-4/24498

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/valueerror-expected-input-batch-size-1-to-match-target-batch-size-64/43071

[Pytorch CNN error: Expected input batch_size (4) to match target batch_size (64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54928638/pytorch-cnn-error-expected-input-batch-size-4-to-match-target-batch-size-64)

Thanks in advance. Your support is truly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this model does not handle multi-target scenario according to [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification):

> labels (torch.LongTensor of shape (batch_size,), optional) – Labels for computing the sequence classification/regression loss. Indices should be in [0, ..., config.num_labels - 1]. If config.num_labels == 1 a regression loss is computed (Mean-Square loss), If config.num_labels > 1 a classification loss is computed (Cross-Entropy).

So, you need prepare your labels to have the shape of `batch_size`: `torch.Size([batch_size])` with class index in a range `[0, ..., config.num_labels - 1]` just like for the original `pytorch`'s [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#crossentropyloss) (see example section).

Comment: The model I am using is not DistilBert but rather the original Bert. The initialization details in the document suggests that it can be used in a multilabel classification setting:

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly to model you are using `BertForSequenceClassification` . But as you can see nothing has changed:  `labels (torch.LongTensor of shape (batch_size,), optional)`, `labels` still should be of shape of batch size.